# Magento - Programmatically Disable Automatic Indexing

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.4

In Magento 1.9 Enterprise (which is essentially the 1.4 Community Edition), what is the correct way to disable the index programmatically so that it wont reindex after every product update?

We have a complex product import procedure, so we can't use the built-in catalog import.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Setting the indexer to "manual" mode will prevent it from automatically indexing on save/edit/delete.

In MAGE_ROOT/shell you can find a script called indexer.php that, between others allows you to enable/disable indexers:

```
php indexer.php --mode-manual catalog_url
php indexer.php --mode-realtime catalog_url
```

You can have a script that sets all the indexers to manual

If you want to do it programatically, something along the lines should work:

```
$pCollection = Mage::getSingleton('index/indexer')->getProcessesCollection(); 
foreach ($pCollection as $process) {
  $process->setMode(Mage_Index_Model_Process::MODE_MANUAL)->save();
  //$process->setMode(Mage_Index_Model_Process::MODE_REAL_TIME)->save();
}
```

Comment: When you turn indexing back on, you may also want to reindex as well with  $process->reindexAll();

Answer (score 1):

You may not have to do it programmatically.  I had a similar issue where I had about 10 files to import.  I couldn't combine as it was a site move and some were dependents on others.

You can turn off automatic index, which if your import script is configured properly will listen to.

It's worth a shot:

```
System -> Index Management
Check All Items
Change Action to "Change Index Mode"
Select "Manual"
Save
```

Hope this helps.