# how to create configurable product through programming in magento

Tags: magento

i want to create configurable product through programming how we can create this?
I have 10000 up simple products and i have to implement functionality that create configurable products from this simple products

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create configurable products same as simple products but give them type as config product and associate simple product id to this config products

Comment: You may also want to turn off product indexing while you are creating the products (it can be turned off programmatically) to speed up your product creation otherwise you may find it taking a while.

Comment: how can we turn off product indexing programmatically?

Comment: i have found link for doing this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5420552/magento-programmatically-disable-automatic-indexing