# Magento 1.7 / 1.8 deadlocks from index_process table

Tags: magento, database-deadlocks

I'm having greate problems with Magento last friday we upgraded Magento from 1.7 to 1.8..

The issue is that we're having a lot of deadlocks in the MySQL database.

Our server setup is

1 Load Balancer
4 Webservers (Apache, PHP5, APC)
2 MySQL Servers (64 GB Ram, 30 cores SSD HDD) - 1 Master (Has Memcache for sessions) - 1 Slave (Has Redis for caching)

The deadlock's is less on Magento 1.8 than 1.7 but the still appear from time to time ..

Any one has some good ideas on how to get pass this problem.

### Heres some data from SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS;

### LATEST DETECTED DEADLOCK

130930 12:03:35
*** (1) TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION 918EEC3B, ACTIVE 37 sec starting index read
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
LOCK WAIT 41 lock struct(s), heap size 6960, 50 row lock(s), undo log entries 6
MySQL thread id 51899, OS thread handle 0x7f9774169700, query id 2583719 xxx.xx.xxx.47 dbxxx Updating
UPDATE `m17_index_process` SET `started_at` = '2013-09-30 10:03:36' WHERE (process_id='8')
*** (1) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 594 page no 3 n bits 208 index `PRIMARY` of table `xxx.xx.xxx.47 dbxxx`.`m17_index_process` trx id 918EEC3B lock_mode X locks rec but not gap waiting
*** (2) TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION 918EE3E7, ACTIVE 72 sec starting index read
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
680 lock struct(s), heap size 80312, 150043 row lock(s), undo log entries 294
MySQL thread id 51642, OS thread handle 0x7f8a336c7700, query id 2586254 xxx.xx.xxx.47 dbxxx Updating
UPDATE `m17_index_process` SET `started_at` = '2013-09-30 10:03:40' WHERE (process_id='8')**
 (2) HOLDS THE LOCK(S):
RECORD LOCKS space id 594 page no 3 n bits 208 index `PRIMARY` of table `dbxxx`.`m17_index_process` trx id 918EE3E7 lock mode S locks rec but not gap
 **(2) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 594 page no 3 n bits 208 index `PRIMARY` of table `dbxxx`.`m17_index_process` trx id 918EE3E7 lock_mode X locks rec but not gap waiting
*** WE ROLL BACK TRANSACTION (1)

Best Regards.
Rasmus

Answer (score 0):

Seems deadlocks are due to indexing processes. Try disabling automatic indexes [Magento - Programmatically Disable Automatic Indexing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5420552/magento-programmatically-disable-automatic-indexing)

and doing them manually.
Also try  disabling cron for some time and check if issues reoccur.

Its  possible that many store admins saving products from different stores. In that case  product save may be causing deadlock with index processes.

Thanks